# How to parameterize a clock divider?

Tags: fpga, verilog, clock, counter

The best clock divider is a PLL inside a FPGA. But the number of PLLs are limited. And sometimes using of counter to divide a clock is justified:

```
reg [7:0]counter = 0;
reg divided_clk = 0;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(counter == DIVIDER - 1) begin
        divided_clk <= ~divided_clk;
        counter <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end
end
```

But the condition

```
    if(counter == DIVIDER - 1) begin
```

use logical elements in non-optimal way.

If we make another condition:

```
if(counter[DIVIDER_POW]) begin
```

we use less LEs but lose an accuracy of dividing.

Also we can find an optimal divider, then decremet the divider by one, then convert the divider to binary and make the condition from elements with one. For example the condition based on the divider equal to 50 looks like:

```
if(counter[5] && counter[4] && counter[0]) begin
```

The accuracy of this condition is the same as the first method. And it takes less LEs.

But is it possible to parameterize such condition?

Comment: I mean... the real answer is "you don't care that you think the LEs will be uses non-optimally in the real world". Congestion will be a problem ages before the extra LEs for a simple clock divider makes your mapping on an FPGA impossible.

Comment: Also, you should probably measure it on a case-by-case basis instead of making the blanket statements. I know plenty toolflows that will optimize the comparison either way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parameterize"? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: It's awfully difficult to estimate how much LEs the optimizer will use… maybe for some parametrization it will be a couple and maybe for other it will be an awful lot with timing issues. The big question usually is *how* that clock will be used: a SPI clock from an FPGA point of view is simply a signal like many others, usually. The big fat clocks given by the PLLs are usually reserved for the machine runs and maybe some peculiar peripheral (like SDRAM). Also passing thru clock domains is a major hassle. In my experience is best to minimize the synchronous clocks

Comment: You want to check whether `counter & DIVIDER == DIVIDER` and then let the synthesis tool ignore the bits where DIVIDER is 0. You could also consider DIVIDER-1 and checking the divider before the increment, in case DIVIDER-1 has less 1 bits than DIVIDER. The lowest value of x where x&y==y is y, and we don't care about the higher values that meet the condition since the counter never gets to them.

Comment: @user253751, counter & DIVIDER == DIVIDER - this is the answer on my question. Thank you! If you would post it as answer, I will check it with a green daw. Also, you may point out that a congestion will be a problem before the extra LEs.

Comment: I think you are being pedantic here. 
For instance Synthesisers like Vivado are too smart to optimise these scenarios to best performance. There are different tool optimization which will help you achieve this.

Comment: See this about using NBAs to your clock signals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790715/2755607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this more generally as `counter & DIVIDER == DIVIDER`. This will check that all the 1 bits in the divider are in the counter, but it won't check the 0 bits, which are not necessary to check. The synthesis tool will certainly optimize out the `anything & 0 == 0` part.

Comment: -1 there could have been a good question and answer here "can you parametrize verilog so that it automatically decides on an architecture decision". But here we are with an answer that has zero bearing on the real world and just reinforces a backward way of thinking by OP.

Comment: @DonFusili, what prevented you from writing your own good answer?

Comment: @Arseniy The fact that I don't know the answer to the interesting question and I didn't want to answer the question as posed because it's a bad one.

Comment: @DonFusili, Hmm.. what prevented you from asked your own good question?